# Features lost when extruding polygons between two TINs

Tags: arcgis-pro, 3d-analyst

I am trying to transform a collection of adjacent simple polygons to a collection of simple polyhedrons. My approach is to create two constant-elevation rasters representing the upper and lower boundaries of the polyhedrons, convert these two rasters to TINs, and then use the [Extrude Between](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/extrude-between.htm) tool to generate the polyhedrons. However, I find that some of the features are lost (see gaps in the figure) and there appears to be some weirdness going on in the edge definitions of the resulting polyhedrons.

If I am not doing something wrong, is there an alternative approach to vertically extruding polygons to create polyhedrons?

[image: top view of extruded result]
[image: shaded side view of extruded result]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the [regularize building footprint](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/regularize-building-footprint.htm) or [regularize adjacent building footprint](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/regularize-adjacent-building-footprint.htm) tool. I opted for the latter because I wanted to ensure that shared borders were handled correctly. Once I did that, the Extrude Between tool output the correct results.